# Taking the limit of sums over squares over an array of numbers.

Tags: sequences-and-series

I want to define a sum that adds a square of the following array from the upper left corner, and then take the limit.
$$\begin{bmatrix} 
-1 & \tfrac {1 }{2 } & \tfrac {1 }{4} & \tfrac {1 }{8 } & \tfrac {1 }{16} & ...\\
0  & -1 & \tfrac {1 }{2 } & \tfrac {1 }{4} & \tfrac {1 }{8 } & ... \\
0  & 0 & -1 & \tfrac {1 }{2} & \tfrac {1}{4} & ... \\ 
0 & 0 & 0 & -1 & \tfrac {1 }{2} & ... \\
. & . & . & . & . & . \\
. & . & . & . & . & . 
\end {bmatrix} 
$$
(The arrays are a little bit messy but I hope you understand)

I tried the following sum 
$\sum _{i=1 }^{n-1} i\frac {1 }{2^{n-i}} - n  $

But I don't know how I could evaluate the limit. Help would be much appreciated!

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Could you please give more detail on why the matrix is there and which matrix terms form the sum? Your proposed sum seems to be the sum over all elements in the upper left $n\times n$ square block, matching your description. The expression $(q-1)^2\sum_{i=1}^n iq^i$ simplifies to 3 terms or so.

Comment: I want to sum all the terms in the finite n by n matrix, seen from the upper left corner of the infinite array. And then expand this matrix to see if it converges to a limit. Is this clearer?

Comment: It was clear in my last comment, "the upper left $n×n$ square block". As per my answer below, the limit is $-2$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you look at the column-sums you get
$$ \left[ \begin{array} {} -1&-1/2&-1/4&-1/8& \cdots \end{array} \right] $$
Evaluation of the upper $n \times n$-submatrix gives just the sum of the first n terms of this column-sums as $$-(1+1/2+1/4+...+1/2^{n-1} ) =- {1-1/2^n\over 1-1/2}=-(2- \frac 1{2^{n-1}})$$ which in the limit is $-2$

Answer (score 1):

Note that

\begin{align}
(q-1)\sum_{k=1}^{n-1} kq^k
&=(q^2-q)+2(q^3-q^2)+3(q^4-q^3)+...+(n-1)(q^{n}-q^{n-1})\\
&=-q-q^2-q^3-...-q^{n-1}+(n-1)q^{n}
\\
&=(n-1)q^{n}-\frac{q^{n}-q}{q-1}
\end{align}

Now set $q=2$ and divide by $2^n$ to get

$$\sum_{k=1}^{n-1} k2^{k-n}=(n-1)-(1-2^{1-n})$$

Comment: Ok great, thanks! How did you know this first realation, and also see to applicate it?

Comment: The summand $(n-1)$ seems wrong to me...

Comment: Starting in which line? The upper bound of the sum is $n-1$. Note that this refers to the sum formula in the question, $\sum_{i=1}^{n-1}\frac{i}{2^{n-i}}-n=-2+\frac1{2^{n-1}}$.

Comment: Hmm, in th second line. The result is then of order n while in my answer I find that it converges to the constant limit -2 . So something must be wrong there... (Or I'm badly missing something very trivial...)

Comment: The sum only sums over the elements above the diagonal. The $n$ diagonal entries $-1$ are added at the end. Your calculation proceeds differently by summing over the columns first, here the sum is over the diagonals first. Result is really the same.

Comment: I see! Thank you for the explanation!